# NextJS useSWR XHR is succesful but variable undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, next.js

In the browser console I get a succesful request XHR to the api endpoint and the data is returned, however when I do a console.log(data1) the variable comes back undefined. What do I need to do to return this data to a nextjs app using useSWR react hook?

```js
const FromDate = "02/01/2020";
const ToDate = "09/30/2020";
const baseURL = `http://example.com/test_db/system.sql?query=`

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }}
    ).then(res => res.json())


function updateDates (FromDate, ToDate) {
    const url = `http://example.com/test_db/system.sql?query=sqlD`

    const { data1, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher)
   console.log("updatefunction", data1)
    return {
      data1,
      isLoading: !error && !data1,
      isError: error
    }
  }
const { data1, isLoading, isError } = updateDates("01/01/2018", "12/31/2019")
```

UPDATE* The error that I receive is:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: I know the api is good because it gets returned server side via nextjs serversideprops -- just not using useSWR

Comment: `const { data1, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher)` shouldn't swr return `data` instead of `data1` ?